# Can't Get ClientMessageInspector to Work with Config

Tags: wcf

I wrote a ClientMessageInspector modeled after this sample [Message Inspection in WCF](http://blog.binarymist.net/2010/06/14/message-inspection-in-wcf/) which I can get to work. I have a service that is a client to other services. It is in a project "Interface12ServiceProject." The MessageInspector is:

```
namespace MessageListener.Instrumentation
{
    public class MessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        private const string LogDir = @"C:\Logs\Interface12Service\";

        private Message TraceMessage(MessageBuffer buffer)
        {
            // Must use a buffer rather than the original message, because the Message's body can be processed only once.
            Message msg = buffer.CreateMessage();

            //Setup StringWriter to use as input for our StreamWriter
            //This is needed in order to capture the body of the message, because the body is streamed
            StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
            XmlTextWriter xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
            msg.WriteMessage(xmlTextWriter);
            xmlTextWriter.Flush();
            xmlTextWriter.Close();

            //Setup filename to write to
            if (!Directory.Exists(LogDir))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(LogDir);

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            string datePart = now.Year.ToString() + '-' + now.Month.ToString() + '-' + now.Day.ToString() + '-' + now.Hour + '-' + now.Minute + '-' + now.Second;
            string fileName = LogDir + "\\" + datePart + '-' + "SoapEnv.xml";

            //Write to file
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
                sw.Write(stringWriter.ToString());

            //Return copy of origonal message with unalterd State
            return buffer.CreateMessage();
        }

        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            reply = TraceMessage(reply.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue));
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
        {
            request = TraceMessage(request.CreateBufferedCopy(int.MaxValue));
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I have a LoggingEndpointBehavior:

```
namespace MessageListener.Instrumentation
{
    public class LoggingEndpointBehavior : IEndpointBehavior
    {
        public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void ApplyClientBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ClientRuntime clientRuntime)
        {
            MessageInspector inspector = new MessageInspector();
            clientRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(inspector);
        }

        public void ApplyDispatchBehavior(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher endpointDispatcher)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void Validate(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then a LoggingBehaviorExtenhsionElement:

```
namespace MessageListener.Instrumentation
{
    public class LoggingBehaviorExtensionElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
    {
        public override Type BehaviorType
        {
            get { return typeof (LoggingEndpointBehavior); }
        }

        protected override object CreateBehavior()
        {
            return new LoggingEndpointBehavior();
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, the relevant configuration is:

```
       <client>
        <endpoint address="..."
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Tier2DocumentEndpointImplServiceSoapBinding"
                contract="SSHIPProdInterface12.Tier2DocumentEndpoint" name="Tier2DocumentEndpointImplPort" behaviorConfiguration="messageInspectorBehavior"/>

    <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="messageInspectorBehavior">
              <messageInspector />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
<extensions>
      <behaviorExtensions>
        <add name="messageInspector" type="MessageListener.Instrumentation.LoggingBehaviorExtensionElement, Interface12ServiceProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
      </behaviorExtensions>
```

When I run my Interface12Service and try to call the other service with the endpointBehavior attached:

```
serviceResponse = client.getTier2Document(authHeader, arg1);
```

I get "The method or operation is not implemented" exception and my breakpoints in the MessageInspector never get hot. When I take off the endpointBehavior the call to the other service succeeds but without message inspection. What am I doing wrong? Can I attach my behavior to a service in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by looking at the stack exception: Validate was throwing a NotImplementedException